# CSS transition -- timing issue

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have two divs I want to transition across the screen to make it look like an infinite loop. I have worked with adjusting setTimeouts and setting an event listener (transitionend), but I keep getting a huge gap between the divs. Here is a link to the js [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/verygreen/obw6sdg5/3/) using the event listener. Below is code I used without using the event listener.

Javascript

```
 var boxWrap = $('#one');
 var boxWrap2 = $('#two');

 boxWrap.addClass('start')
 boxWrap2.addClass('start')

 setInterval(function () {
  boxWrap.removeClass('start')
  boxWrap[0].offsetTop
  boxWrap.addClass('start')
 }, 35000)

setInterval(function () {
  boxWrap2.removeClass('start')
  boxWrap2[0].offsetTop
  boxWrap2.addClass('start')
}, 35000)
```

CSS

```
  .boxWrapper.start {
    transition: right linear 35s;
    right: calc(-144vmin - 80vmin - 200vmin);
   }

   .boxWrapper.boxWrapper2.start {
     transform: translateX(-224vmin);
     transition: right linear 35s;
     right: calc(-144vmin - 80vmin - 200vmin);
  }
```

Tell me if there is anything you need.

Comment: are content in each box text and suppose to be exactly the same ?

Comment: @GCyrillus yes they will be the same

Comment: maybe you can then do something with text-shadow and animation: example http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/grbwgm ;)